# PostgreSQL as an external data source

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to get an external data source to work with PostgreSQL.

This is what I've done so far:

Downloaded and installed the latest 64bit PostgreSQL ODBC drivers
Created a System DSN using the ANSI driver and the supplied credentials.
I tested this successfully by importing data into Excel.

I then tried the following on SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition

```
CREATE MASTER  KEY ENCRYPTION  BY  PASSWORD = 'xxx';

CREATE  DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL xxx
WITH IDENTITY = 'xxx' , SECRET = 'xxx';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE kingfisher
WITH (
LOCATION = ' odbc://xxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432' ,
CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'DSN=Kingfisher' ,
PUSHDOWN = ON,
CREDENTIAL = xxx
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[mv_policy]
(
xxx int etc
)
WITH(LOCATION='xxx.xxx', DATA_SOURCE=kingfisher);
```

This all creates successfully without any errors.

However when I tried to do a select from the external table, I get the following error:

Msg 7320, Level 16, State 110, Line 2
Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)". 105082;Generic ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function .

Has anyone managed to get this to work using external data with PostgreSQL?

Comment: "*However when I tried to do a select from the external table, I get the following error...*" - What is the exact query you're running? Why use an External Table instead of a Linked Server?

Comment: I'm just from a simple select of a column. I used an external table as I didn't think SQL Server could link to a PostgreSQL server using a linked server

Comment: Yes, Linked Servers should be able to connect to any source you have an ODBC driver for. External Tables are essentially the same thing but a bit more limited. You should try creating a Linked Server (which there is a GUI for in SSMS) or post the full error you're currently getting for further help.